# What is the ios equivalent to android xml?

Tags: android, ios, xml, swift, android-layout

So me and my coworker have finished our app in android. Now, im starting ios/swift/xcode. And it seems i have two options: Storyboard (terrible, because it makes a lot of assumptions when i drag and drop things, just like in android). Second, i hard code all the ui, which is a pain, because I have no idea what its going to look like until i run it.

In android i wrote all my layouts in xml, because it was great seeing what my layout would look like constantly, and I had full control of my layout (no assumptions of what the padding would be, margins, and what type of layout). After writing my xml i would hook it all up in java and it was beautiful.

Now in ios, i dont see that kind of development design. And I want to develop in the same way as that or something close, or maybe the "most optimal" practice. I hope someone can provide a really good insight on how to approach this.

Comment: There is one #Main story board that contains list of screen that you want to create like xml . let say you want to create login screen then one #view controller is there for login screen that assign with #story board id ,and it will bind in side that #Main story board.

Comment: It looks like you haven't done any research. Read this first: [https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraintsinInterfaceBuidler.html]

Comment: @MaxPevsner your link doesn't work.

Comment: @TheQ sorry, there was a mistype. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraintsinInterfaceBuidler.html

Comment: USe storyBoard and set constraints so it will be in place as you create on a constraint layout in android xml

Answer (score 1):

Like Android XML, iOS also used XML file for Designing the UI part call Storyboard or nib file. if you could Right-Click and select Open As "Source code" you will find XML code their.

The way android used Layout for UI is different from iOS. iOS used Auto-layout technology to set Margin and layout. So you could only go for Drag and drop UI in screens of go for adding UI element programatically.

Comment: in android, if i want to add padding or margins, i could do that in xml. Just making sure im clear here. If i want to space things, i have to do that in storyboard? But if i did drag and drop, wouldn't it also auto set other properties of that button like (ex.) gravity etc.?

Comment: In iOS, little complex than android, for spacing you could use Constraints(Autolayout), for property use "Attribute Inspector" in right for padding as well, also subclssing is options

Comment: Yeah i see, i guess I'll have to start jumping into it and start to figure it out. Thanks for the tips man. Im going to take your advice and the others as i go forward with ios!

Comment: @TheQ. Thanks. ping me anytime.

Comment: Yeah man I will, so look forward to it as i go forward!

Answer (score 1):

You can see development design side by side by switch to Assistant editor which is available on top right side of Xcode. Then select preview. It will be the almost same as in real device.Check these image you will get clear idea

Before this you have select one ViewController which you want to check.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Ah i see, okay that will help a lot as i go forward. Thanks for the input man, I will take this into account as i go forward!